# calculus area under the curve approximation

Tags: calculus

Whenever we are taking area under the curve we leave  some area while calculating the area. We take it for a small change in x and then add it. But at the end there is some part of the total area which is left. Is integration an approximation?

Comment: As a rule the area is defined starting from the integral, not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

The integral is defined using limits.  The things you are taking the limit of are approximations.